# Is there a difference between MaxClient value for mpm prefork and worker?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker

I would like to know if there is a difference between MaxClient value for mpm prefork and worker.

I'm actualy capable of calculating this value for mpm_prefork (${ALLOWEDMEM} / ${AVGMEMAPACHEUSED} )but can the same value be set for worker/event mpm without any problems , or does it have to be adjusted for each mpm ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaxClients has the same functionality for both mpm.

The difference lies in the mpm itself, as MaxClients is counted in threads with worker, and with processes (child processes) in prefork since it is not multithreaded.